# Calculate gradient of norm of a vector with respect to a vector in python

Tags: python, numpy, vector, gradient, norm

I want to calculate gradient    (f(v(X)))
where     f(a) : second_norm(a);

```
X : a vector of 1*n dimension :: as an example for n == 2:  [x1, x2]
v(X) : (((x1)^m)*P + ((x2)^m)*Q)/(x1^m + x2^m);
```

where P and Q are vectors

So is there any function in python which can help me with this? If so, please elaborate.

I really need help!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your function P and Q should be two vectors of the same dimension.
In this case it's enough to use numpy array.
I put a very simple code that may help you:

```
import numpy as np
x1=2
x2=5
a=[x1,x2]
m=5

P=np.array([1,2,3,4])
Q=np.array([5,6,7,8])

print((  (a[0]**m)*P +(a[1]**m)*Q   )/(a[0]**m  + a[1]**m))
```

Output:
array([4.95945518, 5.95945518, 6.95945518, 7.95945518])

In general if you want to multiply a vector with a scalar you need to use numpy array.

Comment: I need to find out gradient(f(V(X))) not just V(X) using python gradient functions and n=2 is just an example; n is some large unknown number;

Comment: Right, sorry.  If x1 and x2 are your coordinates then you should apply the operator "nabla" to your function.  If you write your V(x) as [(x1^m)*P/(x1^m + x2^m)]   +  [(x2^m)*Q/(x1^m + x2^m)]   then the differential of that is:
[(m(x2^m)*(x1^(m-1))*P/(x1^m + x2^m)^2 ] (i)   +   (m(x1^m)*(x2^(m-1))*Q/(x1^m + x2^m)^2 ]  (j).   Where (i) and (j) are the two components.
This formula can be then applied to every x1 x2 couple.
Give also a look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient